# How to configure intellisense on vscode with unity and linux?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, mono

I recently switched to Linux and I have problems with Unity and VSCode.
When I open any of my scripts, classes like `MonoBehaviour` don't exist...
I found that you should change `Omnisharp: Use Global Mono` to always, but that option doesn't exist. (I have C# extension and mono installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who has this issue:

Assuming everything else is up to date, changing `Use Global Mono` to `always` does work. You have to revert to an older version of the C# extension to see the option in settings. 1.24.4 works for me. You can do this by going to the extensions tab, and clicking the gear icon next to the C# extension, and choosing `Install Another Version...`

Found the solution here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-unity-with-vs-code-and-intellisense-on-linux-mint.986088/

Comment: Unity start VS Code in a virtual workspace and OmniSharp does not support virtual workspaces.